# No listener, Adapter error

Tags: oracle, listener

It happened when I moved folder content from c:/users/"user" to other user_name (i wanted change name of package). Unfortunately listeners has been deleted and i cant make another (Net configuration assisstant shows me "cant create listener"). When I use command it shows me:

lsnrctl status

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory
```

lsnrctl start

```
Unable to OpenSCManager: err=5
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
 TNS-00530: Protocol adapter error
```

**listener.ora**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\Xavizo\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = E:\app\Xavizo\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:E:\app\Xavizo\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )

HOTEL =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EwciaPC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = EwciaPC)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

**tns.ora**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: E:\app\Xavizo\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORACLE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = oracle)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORACLE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

Sorry for my english. Hope you can help resolve my problem.

Comment: i cannot login to SQL Plus using existing account and even using "/as sysdba"

Answer (score 21):

1. right click `powershell` and choose `run as Administrator`
2. type `lsnrctl start LISTENER` (or your listener name)

Answer (score 1):

Used this command on powershell with run as Administrator then my problem has resolved.

lsnrctl start
And
lsnrctl status

Answer (score 0):

It's very frustrating to not able to connect to Oracle even with `localhost` setting.

For me, I have to set the listener to listen on all IP address with `0.0.0.0`

Below is my configuration setting:
**listener.ora**

```
# listener.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\thanglequoc\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1\NETWORK\ADMIN\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = XE

SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\app\thanglequoc\product\21c\dbhomeXE)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:C:\app\thanglequoc\product\21c\dbhomeXE\bin\oraclr.dll")
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
  )
```

**tnsnames.ora**

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: C:\app\thanglequoc\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1\NETWORK\ADMIN\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

LISTENER_XE =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )
```

Then open CMD/Powershell as Administrator, and start the listener with command

```
lsnrctl start
```

and verify the status with

```
lsnrctl status
```

Make sure that your db service are successfully binded with handler, it should have something like this

```
C:\Windows\system32>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 13-NOV-2021 07:22:59

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                13-NOV-2021 07:19:34
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 3 min. 25 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Default Service           XE
Listener Parameter File   C:\app\thanglequoc\product\21c\homes\OraDB21Home1\network\admin\listener.ora
Listener Log File         C:\app\thanglequoc\product\21c\diag\tnslsnr\Ivy\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=0.0.0.0)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(PIPENAME=\\.\pipe\EXTPROC1521ipc)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=C:\APP\THANGLEQUOC\PRODUCT\21C\admin\XE\xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "2af32cd23e1b490aa03bef05d5c26f6c" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "CLRExtProc" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "CLRExtProc", status UNKNOWN, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xepdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

C:\Windows\system32>
```

Answer (score 0):

In My case the service "XXXXMTSRecoveryService" was stopped , so when I started this the listener I configured came up and at listening state.

[image: Sample Image]